# Which of the following sets are connected? 1

Tags: general-topology

Which of the following sets are connected?

a. The set of all points in the plane with at least one coordinate irrational.

b. An infinite set X with the topology τ given by
$τ = ${X, ∅}$ ∪ ${A ⊂ X |   X\A is a finite set} .

my trial : i thinks option a) is not connected as  as rational number are not conneceted as same as irrational...

option b is connected  because   it is not hausdorff....

Is my answer is correct or not or pliz check it  and give me some hints or solution .

thanks in advances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is connected because it is path connected: you can go to one such point to another such point along lines with an irrational coordinate. The same would be true for points with at least one rational coordinate.

b) is indeed not Hausdorff, since any two non-empty open sets intersect. But 'not Hausdorff' does not imply 'connected'! In fact, space b) is not connected: again, because any two non-empty open sets intersect.

Comment: but rational is not connected,,,im not getting..

Comment: The rational numbers on the real line are not connected. But here we are talking of the plane. Do you know the definition of 'path-connected' and that it implies 'connected'?

Comment: thanks a lots  i got it @57jimmy